# getting NoReverseMatch for a correct url and correct arguments

Tags: python, django

I have looked thoroughly my code and yet I am still stuck at this point where I get the NoReverseMatch error for correct url and correct parameters.

Here is my URLConfig

```
 url(r'profile/$', views.agent_profile, name='agent_profile'),
        url(r'profile/(?P<pk>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/$', views.change_profile, name='change_profile'),
        url(r'assign/(?P<pk>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/profile/(?P<profile>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/$', views.assign_profile, name='assign_profile'),
```

the view handling that request is :

```
def assign_profile(request, pk, profile):
    agent = Agent.objects.get(pk=pk)
    # profile = Profile.objects.filter(designation=profile)
    # profile.agents = agent
    return render(request,
                    'portfolio/change_profile.html',
                    {'agent': agent})
```

and the url in the template is called as follow:

```
<li><a href={% url 'portfolio:assign_profile' pk=agent.code_agent profile="super_agent" %}>Super Agent</a></li>
```

and the error is as follow:

```
NoReverseMatch at /portfolio/profile/1/
Reverse for 'assign_profile' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '1', 'profile': 'super_agent'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['portfolio/assign/(?P<pk>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/profile/(?P<profile>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/portfolio/profile/1/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'assign_profile' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '1', 'profile': 'super_agent'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['portfolio/assign/(?P<pk>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/profile/(?P<profile>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\admin\\PycharmProjects\\trial',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 3 Jan 2018 14:35:49 +0000
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `profile="super_agent"`, but in your regex `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` doesn't include underscores.

```
url(r'assign/(?P<pk>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/profile/(?P<profile>[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/$', views.assign_profile, name='assign_profile'),
```

You could also use `[\w-]+`, which matches uppercase A-Z, lowercase a-z, digits 0-9, hyphens and underscores. If your primary key is an integer, then `[0-9]+` should be enough. Putting that together, you have:

```
url(r'assign/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/profile/(?P<profile>[\w-]+)/$', views.assign_profile, name='assign_profile'),
```